# Laravel: Multiple tables in one model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following model for Users:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'login_info';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function getDashboards()
    {
        return \DB::table('dashboard')
               ->select('type')
               ->where('id', Auth::id())
               ->orderBy('column', 'asc')
               ->get();
    }
}
```

Users have different information in many tables

- user info like name, office, dashboard,2FA etc

Is the way I do it now **"best practice"** (like the `getDashboards` function) for getting information from different tables?

Or should I create a model for each of the tables and then **"join them"** (`hasMany`, `belongsToMany`, and so on) for each of the tables?

**EDIT:**

I am now using models, but the result of the query is always an empty array.

```
class Dashboard extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'dashboard';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
        //user_id
    }
}
```

`user_id` is the id of the user which is used in the login_info table.

And in the User class I have:

```
public function dashboards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Dashboard::class,'id','user_id');
}
```

In the login controller I have:

```
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$user->dashboards;
```

Anyone see what the problem could be?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You should create a separate model for each table

Comment: definitely **create a model for each of the tables**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function dashboards()
{return $this->hasMany(\App\Dashboard::class);
}
```

And in your Dashboard Model you do it this way

```
protected $casts = [
        'user_id' => 'int',
    ];
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);
    }
```

Comment: Sweet, that worked! What was the problem with the way I had done it, thought that was the right way?

Comment: you forget casts,and the way you had declared it

Comment: I see. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

The more Laravel way is to rather created the related `Dashboard` model and use the eloquent relationships, and harness the features of the ORM. Nothing wrong to include an `orderBy` on the relationship if you always need ordering on that column.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function dashboards()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Dashboard::class)
            ->orderBy('column', 'asc');
    }
}

class Dashboard extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do anything in the model! Just refer to the model in the controller, for example:

```
User::where('id', Auth::id())->pluck('type');
```